# Как дать transition на короткое время?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, анимация

Как сделать плавный переход? То есть если оттянуть картинку до угла, а потом навести курсор на другой угол она резко дернется, а нужно плавно.

[Вот здесь](https://gijsroge.github.io/tilt.js/) есть решение - `transition` дается на короткое время, за это время плавность срабатывает и `transition` убирается, но я не понимаю как это реализовано. Если же просто повесить на `.for-trans` `transition`, то будет некорректно выглядеть искажение.

```js
var mpHeight = $('.main-page').height();
var mpWidth = $('.main-page').width();

$('.main-page').mousemove(function() {
 var cX = event.clientX;
 var cY = event.clientY;
  
  if (cX < mpWidth/2) {
   cX = event.clientX - mpWidth/2;
  } else {
   cX = event.clientX - mpWidth/2;
  }
  
  if (cY < mpHeight/2) {
   cY = event.clientY - mpHeight/2;
  } else {
   cY = event.clientY - mpHeight/2;
  }
 
  $('.for-trans').css({
   "transform" : "scale(1.2) perspective(1000px) rotateX(" + cY/54  + "deg) rotateY(" + cX/46 + "deg)"
  });
});
```

```css
.main-page {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
}
a {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background: green;
}
.some-content {
  padding-top: 100px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  color: #fff;
}
.for-trans {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url(http://on-desktop.com/wps/Animals___Wild_cats_The_head_of_the_evil_lion__gray_background_100073_.jpg) 50% 50%;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mp" class="main-page">
  <div class="for-trans"></div>
  <div class="some-content">
    <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Выйти lorem послушавшись первую эта семь своих, которое мир рекламных, там буквоград рыбного рукописи продолжил своего курсивных буквенных подзаголовок коварный.</p>
    <a href="#">ссылка</a>
    
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var mpHeight = $('.main-page').height();
var mpWidth = $('.main-page').width();

$('.main-page').mousemove(function() {
  var cX = event.clientX;
  var cY = event.clientY;

  if (cX < mpWidth / 2) {
    cX = event.clientX - mpWidth / 2;
  } else {
    cX = event.clientX - mpWidth / 2;
  }

  if (cY < mpHeight / 2) {
    cY = event.clientY - mpHeight / 2;
  } else {
    cY = event.clientY - mpHeight / 2;
  }

  $('.for-trans').css({
    "transform": "  rotateX(" + cY / 54 + "deg) rotateY(" + cX / 46 + "deg)"
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
}

.main-page {
  overflow: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 700px;
  height: 320px;
}

.for-trans {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 120%;
  height: 120%;
  margin: -10% 0 0 -10%;
  background: url(http://img11.nnm.me/f/7/c/9/6/6a4ae327a93ca29b06ff90615ed.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

a {
  display: block;
  background: green;
}

.some-content {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 70%;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mp" class="main-page">
  <div class="for-trans">

    <div class="some-content">
      <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Выйти lorem послушавшись первую эта семь своих, которое мир рекламных, там буквоград рыбного рукописи продолжил своего курсивных буквенных подзаголовок коварный.</p>
      <a href="#">ссылка</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```